Get jinja2 macro parameter names in dbt?
I'm trying to find a way to extract all the parameters' names in a dbt jinja macro. So far the only place where I have found this data is manifest.json but apparently it is not accessible from dbt itself. Is there any way to do this?
The context of my question is that I'm trying to build a decorating macro that validates the parameters that have been passed to another macro (e.g. if my_macro takes a unique parameter called param, then doing my_macro(paran = 'value') or my_macro(param = 'value', other_param = 'other_value') throw errors. This can easily be done for one specific macro by writing down explicitly its valid parameter names, but I would like to do this dynamically so I can apply it to every macro. Any ideas?
Just in case, I'm using dbt Cloud, not Core.
So far I tried accessing the manifest.json file within dbt but it doesn't seem to be possible. I've also looked into the context variable but cannot find any thorough documentation about its functionality.

Are you sure that's necessary? It seems like dbt/Jinja enforce this for you already. When I make a basic macro:
-- macros/my_macro.sql

{% macro my_macro(param) %}
  {{ param }}
{% endmacro %}

and try to call it with different arguments, I get errors as follows:
{{ my_macro(paran='hello') }}
-- macro 'dbt_macro__my_macro' takes no keyword argument 'paran'

{{ my_macro(param='hello', other_param='world') }}
-- macro 'dbt_macro__my_macro' takes no keyword argument 'other_param'

{{ my_macro('hello', 'world') }}
-- macro 'dbt_macro__my_macro' takes not more than 1 argument(s)


We were told at work that it would be nice to modify these errors to make them more "user friendly" since we have people who are very well versed on SQL but not Jinja/Python and programming in general. This is the approach I came up with, but it seems needlessly complicated anyway...
